# how to debug PHP/WordPress failure running on WebMatrix (Windows 7)

Tags: webmatrix

I was able to install and run WordPress via WebMatrix on a VM.  I have a WordPress theme though that immediately causes the site to start failing.  I receive a 500 error message, there is nothing in my event logs.

Where can I find some kind of log for what actually happened?  Or is there a way I can have the site show detailed error information?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you are having trouble. WebMatrix runs sites in the context of IIS Express, the included lightweight web server. Its logs can be found in:

\IISExpress\Logs
\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

found this [Enable xDebug in WebMatrix](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2011/02/18/how-to-enable-xdebug-in-webmatrix.aspx).

hope this helps.